# The evaluation of Complex integration

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

$K>0$

$C_K$ : $z=(K-t)+it \,\,(0\leqq t \leqq K)$ (Straight Line on $\mathbb{C}$)

Prove that

(i) $|z|\geqq \dfrac{K}{\sqrt{2}}$ for $z\in C_K$

(ii) $\bigg|\dfrac{e^{iz}}{z}\bigg|\leqq \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{K} e^{-t}$ for $z\in C_K$

(iii) $\lim_{K\to \infty} \displaystyle\int_{C_K} \dfrac{e^{iz}}{z} dz=0$

I could prove (i) and (ii), but I cannot prove (iii) .

\begin{align}
\Bigg| \displaystyle\int_{C_K} \dfrac{e^{iz}}{z} dz \Bigg|
&\leqq \sup_{z\in C_K} \Bigg| \dfrac{e^{iz}}{z} \Bigg| \cdot L(C_K) \\
&\leqq \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{K}e^{-t}\cdot L(C_K) \\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{K}e^{-t}\cdot \sqrt{K^2+K^2} \\
&=2e^{-t}.
\end{align}

The term $K$ vanishes so it didn't work.

I would like you to give me some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply start to evaluate the integral,
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \int_{C_K} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz \right \rvert &=\left\lvert
\int_0^K \frac{e^{(K-t)i-t}}{(K-t)+it} \cdot(-1+i) dt \right\rvert\\
&\leqslant\sqrt{2}\int_0^K \frac{e^{-t}}{\lvert (K-t) + it\rvert} dt 
\end{align}
The denominator is bounded below by $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} K$, so you obtain,
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \int_{C_K} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz \right \rvert &\leqslant\frac{2}{K} \int_0^K e^{-t} dt \\
&=\frac{2(1-e^{-K})}{K}
\end{align}
and this last term has limit zero as $K \to \infty$.

---

Comment on approach taken:  the approximation using the length of $C_K$ and the maximum value of the integrand doesn't work because it cannot exploit the fact that $e^{iz}$ decreases rapidly along $C_K$.  Moreover, in the answer you gave you still have a term $e^{-t}$, but the $t$ variable is only relevant inside the integral and therefore should never appear as part of the final estimate.